# jquery next not working on next div, can't add class

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble activating a child class.

https://jsfiddle.net/d36k2L3c/2/

I'm building a checkbox system of sorts and would like not only the "check box" to activate, but also change the color of the child div as well.  The code changes the checkbox as desired, but does nothing to the child div.

Anyone able to help me out, help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks,

```
<div class="question">
  <div class="question_check">
<div id="qid" class="question_check_box"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="question_content">This is the question</div>
</div>

 $(".question_check_box").on().click(function () {
$(this).toggleClass("question_check_box question_checked_box").next(".question_content").addClass("grey");

});
$(".question_checked_box").on().click(function () {
$(this).toggleClass("question_checked_box question_check_box").next(".question_content").removeClass("grey");
});
```

Comment: share the error you get in the console

Comment: `next` does not select child nodes, it selects siblings. Try `find`.

Comment: use .closest() instead of .next() to get the parent class selector

Comment: .closest() and find() doesn't work either.  I forgot to mention that I do have a fiddle above in case anyone missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `.next()` alone is not going to work is because  `question_check_box` is not a sibling of `question_content` . So you would first need to navigate to the parent of `question_check_box` ( i.e, `question_check` ) and then use the `.next()` function.

```
 $(".question_check_box").on().click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("question_check_box question_checked_box").closest(".question_check").next(".question_content").addClass("grey");
 });

 $(".question_checked_box").on().click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("question_checked_box question_check_box").closest(".question_check").next(".question_content").removeClass("grey");
 });
```

Comment: Yep, that worked, not sure why you need both, but regardless changed the addClass and removeClass to toggleClass and works as intended.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your script:

```
$(".question_check_box, .question_checked_box").on("click",function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("question_check_box question_checked_box")
    .parent().parent().find(".question_content").toggleClass("grey");

 });
```